# Show/Add Administrator overlay icon to Inno Setup installer?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, elevated-privileges, shortcut-file

I wanna know how to add Administrator overlay icon to my Inno Setup installers.

Like on this image:

[image]

Comment: This mini icon is automatically added by Windows if it discovers that aplication requires Administrative Rules.

Comment: Ok so how to make the setup requieres Administrative Rules, i added this: [Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin, but dont work

Comment: Same here, I'm also looking for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible.

The icon is added for applications that have `requireAdministrator` (or maybe `highestAvailable`) execution level set in their manifests:

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
```

Inno Setup installers do not have that set. They elevate themselves internally, instead of relying on system to do that for them.

---

*Interestingly, there is [`UpdateManifestRequestedExecutionLevel` function](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_9/Projects/ResUpdate.pas#L337) in Inno Setup code that does this, but it's never called.*

Comment: Is there any way to embed this into a manifest without using mt.exe ?

Comment: @DARKGuy I do not understand what `mt.exe` has to do with this question.

Comment: Inno Setup installers do not have a way to embed a manifest into the output EXE file. If you use the mt.exe to embed the manifest inside it, it trims the extra data out of the EXE file leaving you with a corrupt file. I also tried to add a .manifest file with the same name and a simple XML boilerplate using your suggested fields and Windows doesn't mark it as admin anyways. I understand they somehow "elevate" themselves, however in my case I don't see the setup elevating anything. No UAC prompt is displayed and my setup crashes with: Code 1314, A required priviledge is not held by the user.

Comment: My answer starts *"I do not think this is possible."* - And I still mean it. The rest of the answer is just an explanation why it does not work. It's not a guide how to fix it.